# Can putting tracing paper on window create enough privacy?

Tags: windows

Just moved in to a new flat and will be doing blinds etc.

Right now I don’t have anything someone suggested to me to use tracing paper.  Apparently so long as you don’t touch it nobody will be able to make out what your doing inside so long as you don’t go right up to it and they won’t be able to see your shadow even with the light on.

Is this correct?  I previously used semi sheer curtains and they didn’t give the amount of privacy needed.  Is tracing paper a lot better than semi sheer or no?

Thanks

Comment: Newspaper is cheaper and there's almost no chance of shadows, etc. It's a classic!  Otherwise, this question is virtually unanswerable as none of us can say for sure exactly what is "enough privacy" for you. Consider revising this question to make it a candidate for a fact-based answer.

Comment: it is for you to try it and evaluate the result

Comment: Foam wrap works great [eBay examples](https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Foam-Wraps/109704/bn_78212851) You can even pleat it like net curtains & sellotape it to the inside of the frames. Unless shadows fall on it, it is totally opaque/private, yet lets just as much light in as nets. We use it on a couple of windows here that are badly overlooked by anyone passing.

Comment: @Tetsujin that will kill you quickly in the event of a fire....

Comment: @Ecnerwal - it would go up at about the same speed as the curtains in front of it & slightly quicker than the plastic window frames behind it.

Comment: Curtains in most civilized countries are required to have flame-retardant treatments. Fabric does not produce the "extra-toxic smoke" that plastic foam does.

Comment: i used a white table"cloth" (plastic sheeting basically) from dollar tree, 100% opaque but passes 90% of the light through.

Comment: doubling any light filtering material MORE than doubles how much vision it blocks; two layers of sheer fabric is darn near opaque.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's roughly the same effect as frosted glass.

The more your lights are between you and the window, the less you'll put on a shadow-play. Also the less your lights that *are* beyond you casting shadows on the window are point sources, the less detailed the shadow-play. Shading and aiming of lights can be beneficial in reducing the amount of perceivable detail to someone outside.

"Enough" privacy is subjective/opinion/varies with who you are. You could always turn on a single point source pointing right at the window and have fun with shadow-puppets...you'll know just who the nosy neighbors are when they start complaining that you can't keep a dragon in this neighborhood, and you innocently ask why they think you have a dragon...

Comment: _"...you can't keep a dragon in this neighborhood...'_ - nice!